# Using range() in For Loop (Python 3.3.3)

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.3

I have googled the whole internets and can't find the reason why I get this error when using range() function:

```
>>> for x in range(5):
     print "Hello World!"

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect 5 Hello Worlds there.

It's ok on Python 2.7, but on Python 3.3.3 (64bits, Windows 8.1) I get this error.
Could anybody advice how can I make loops in Python 3.3.3? Is it bug or something has changed a lot since 2.7 regarding "For"?

Thanks. :/

Comment: `print` is a function in Python3

Comment: The whole internets?  You need a new browser, it's suppressing results for some reason.  :^)  The first google result for "python 3.3 syntax error" explains the problem.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't imagine that Print() is the guilty one. :) Was too confident that problem was in range. My fault!

Comment: "Yes, but I couldn't imagine that Print() is the guilty one. :)" - this is why Python error messages have those `^` symbols in them: to point at where the error was detected. (In 3.11 and up, they can underline entire words as appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

`print` is a function in Python 3, you need to put parentheses:

```
for x in range(5): 
    print("Hello World!")
```

From the [official website](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> The print statement has been replaced with a print() function, with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the old print statement ([PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105)).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, [`print` is a function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print), so you must call it with parentheses `()`:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Stupid me. :) 
Thanks and Sorry! This worked.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 and above print is a function so try writing

```
for x in range(5): print("Hello World!")
```